# ODB get VIN (vehicle identification number)

Tags: obd-ii

I am try to get vin using obd command "0902\r". I did that on 2 cars (hyiunday tucson 2007 and a toyota avensis 2008) but wasn t able to. Is that because those cars doesn t have VIN function or I am doing something wrong?

hyundai:

```
Voltage :12.45
PROTO NAME :AUTO, ISO 14230-4 (KWP FAST)
>

PROTO NUMBER :A5
>

VIN:49 02 01 00 00 00 FF 
49 02 02 FF FF FF FF 
49 02 03 FF FF FF FF 
49 02 04 FF FF FF FF 
49 02 05 FF FF FF FF 
>
```

toyota

```
Voltage :12.16
PROTO NAME :AUTO, ISO 14230-4 (KWP 5BAUD)
>
PROTO NUMBER :A4
>
VIN:7F 09 22 
>
```

Thank you

Comment: seems that car doesn t have the vin set in the ecu...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to Get VIN Number response from OBD-2 Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158165/unable-to-get-vin-number-response-from-obd-2-device)